# Segunda resposta do Web Service ainda tem o valor da primeira

Tags: android, web-service, thread

A primeira coisa que eu faço na minha aplicação é enviar uma mensagem para o servidor, somente para testar se a conexão está ativa e funcionando. Ao receber "ok" do servidor eu continuo a aplicação.

Na próxima tela eu tenho que mostrar uma lista de nomes, portanto eu faço a requisição da lista. Porém não mostra nada na primeira vez que eu inicio a tela, para que apareça algo eu preciso recarregar a tela, como quando viro o celular de retrato para paisagem. Ela também aparece se eu colocar um botão que força a tela a ser recriada.

Após alguns testes eu identifiquei que a lista não estava aparecendo de primeira por que o conteúdo que ela estava recebendo era o "ok", que eu recebo ao fazer a verificação de conexão. Também identifiquei que o Log responsável por mostrar o que esta chegando das requisições feitas (na função abaixo em anexo) estava correto, mostrando ter recebido a lista de nomes, porem reparei também que ele está sendo mostrado após o Log que coloquei na função que pega a informação da função abaixo. Como isso é possível? Eu chamei uma função e coloquei um objeto para pegar o retorno, porém o objeto tem um valor definido antes do retorno da minha função. E esse valor definido é o valor da minha ultima requisição.

Estou utilizando essa biblioteca: compile `org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2`

> Exemplo: a requisição inicial pega a resposta certa, a dela. Até porque é a >primeira, já a requisição da lista que é a 2ª pega a resposta da 1ª >requisição. Se eu recarrego a página isso quer dizer que é feita uma nova >requisição, certo? Que seria a requisição da lista. Agora a lista aparece, >mas ela aparece por que ela pegou a resposta da 2ª requisição, que também é >uma lista. A resposta da 3ª requisição não foi utilizada, e se eu fizer uma >4ª requisição essa irá pegar as informações da 3ª e assim por diante.

Segue abaixo o código utilizado para fazer as requisições.

```
public class HttpConnection {
    public static String getSetDataWeb(String url, String method, String data) throws URISyntaxException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        String answer = "";

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            // Setamos nossa URI
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            // Executamos nossa transação HTTP
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            // Pegamos o conteúdo advindo como resposta e inserimos em um InputStream
            answer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("RESPOSTAhttp", answer);    
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        return(answer);
    }
}
```

Função que envia a URL requisitada para o httpConnection

```
public static String comandaDetalhes(final String numCartao) throws SQLException {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    n = HttpConnection.getSetDataWeb("http://192.168.1.20:7070/comanda/detalhes/"+numCartao, "", "");
                } catch(Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }.start();

        return n;
    }
```

Função que pede a lista de nomes para a função que utiliza o httpConnection

```
public List<Conteudo> getComandaDetalhes(){
        conteudosL = new ArrayList<>();
        //--------INICIO PEGAR ComandaS---------
        if(chamadas == 0){
            try {
                String teste = ComandaDAO.comandaDetalhes(getIntent().getStringExtra("NumeroCartao"));
                Log.d("DETALHESCOMANDA", teste);
                if(teste != "Comanda inexistente!"){
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(teste);
                    chamadas =0;
                    JSONArray jaBebidas = new JSONArray(jo.getString("bebidas"));
                    Log.d("RESPOSTADetalhesBebidas", String.valueOf(jaBebidas));
                    JSONArray jaPratos = new JSONArray(jo.getString("pratos"));
                    Log.d("RESPOSTADetalhesPratos", String.valueOf(jaPratos));
                    JSONArray jaComanda = new JSONArray(jo.getString("comanda"));
                    Log.d("RESPOSTADetalhesComanda", String.valueOf(jaComanda));

                    for(int i = 0; i<jaBebidas.length(); i++){
                        jo = jaBebidas.getJSONObject(i);
                        Conteudo conteudos = new Conteudo();
                        conteudos.setNome("x" + jo.getInt("quantidade_bebidas_comanda")
                                + "  " + jo.getString("nome_bebida") + "  R$ "
                                + jo.getDouble("preco_bebida"));
                        conteudosL.add(conteudos);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i<jaPratos.length(); i++){
                        jo = jaPratos.getJSONObject(i);
                        Conteudo conteudos = new Conteudo();
                        conteudos.setNome("x" + jo.getInt("quantidade_pratos_comanda")
                                + "  " + jo.getString("nome_prato") + "  R$ "
                                + jo.getDouble("preco_prato"));
                        Log.d("PratoAdicionado", conteudos.getNome());
                        conteudosL.add(conteudos);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return conteudosL;
    }
```

Comment: A pergunta está muito confusa, simplifique, coloque o(s) trecho do código onde o problema ocorre.

Comment: Tentei explicar ao máximo o que está acontecendo, dei uma editada para ver se ficava melhor. Realmente está confusa, mas não sei como explicar melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo, na sua função `comandaDetalhes`, você inicia uma Thread mas, imediatamente, retorna essa variável `n`, que é a variável que vai receber o valor da resposta quando essa terminar, esperando que n já tenha o valor esperado (ou que só retorne quando tenha). Isso não vai acontecer.

Na segunda chamada a `comandaDetalhes`, o valor de `n` retornado o valor que foi atribuído na primeira resposta, ou seja, o "OK". O que você precisa entender aqui é que `return n` **(provavelmente) roda antes** de

```
n = HttpConnection.getSetDataWeb("http://192.168.1.20:7070/comanda/detalhes/"+numCartao, "", "");
```

Programação assíncrona é diferente. Não adianta tentar transformar um código que usa Threads num código sequencial que não vai dar certo. O melhor é aprender o paradigma de verdade senão você sempre vai cair nessas armadilhas.

Além disso, tem outros problemas, sendo o mais alarmante o fato de você estar engolindo exceções. Isso é um tiro no pé imenso, porque quando o *bug* aparecer (e ele *[vai](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_de_Murphy)* aparecer), você vai precisar de toda informação e mensagem de erro que for possível obter.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo comentário cara. Realmente me falta experiência no trabalho com Threads como você pode ter notado, mas, eu fiz desta maneira por que não encontrei outra forma de pegar informações da Thread e retorna-las. Pra ser sincero essa foi a minha primeira vez trabalhando com Threads. Ficaria muito grato se você pudesse me informar como eu posso estar realizando isso. O que você disse faz sentido sim. Mas você tem alguma ideia do que fazer ali para acabar com o problema?

Comment: Também não entendi muito bem o por que do n continuar com o valor de antes, a classe que estou utilizando só a utilizo para fazer a função, ela não fica rodando. Inclusive esse erro ocorre até quando faço uso de outra classe. Por Exemplo: Tenho uma classe responsável por pegar os dados da comanda e uma outra pra pegar bebidas, porém esse erro acontece com a função de pegar bebidas, que é de outra classe, a qual ainda não foi utilizada para nenhuma requisição.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitt Um palpite: n é uma variável estática?

Comment: Entendi, então não interessa o número de instancias da classe a variável vai ser 1 só por ela ser static? É isso?
Mas isso ai explicaria o porque quando eu vou em detalhes ele pega a resposta anterior, já que realmente as duas funções (a de confirmação e da lista de Detalhes) pertencem a mesma classe e utilizam a mesma variável. Mas, por que isso continua acontecendo quando eu utilizo outra função de outra Classe para pegar os valores do Web Service após eu fazer a confirmação? Por que ai nesse caso eu não estaria utilizando a mesma variável static.

Comment: Mas a outra função da outra classe não chama essas funções que você colocou aqui para fazer as requisições?

Comment: A única função que ela chama é a do httpConnection. Ela possui outras funções no estilo da função comandaDetalhes que coloquei.
Ela não utiliza a mesma variável static que comandaDetalhes utiliza, mas mesmo assim ela pega a informação que estaria na variável static de comandaDetalhes.

Comment: Não tem um meio de eu forçar a espera do retorno que eu quero pra depois enviar não? Por que eu vi que em java se utiliza o join(), mas eu tentei e não deu certo.

Comment: Threads nativas do Java, em geral, são exagero no Android e trazem mais dificuldades do que ajudam. O ambiente do Android foi projetado com algumas restrições em mente que não combinam com o uso de Threads. A alternativa é a AsyncTask. Para efeito de comparação, se conseguir entender mais ou menos, dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20206314/1796236) no SOEn que compara a mesma tarefa usando Threads e AsyncTasks. Por fim, acredito que deve existir alguma biblioteca de mais alto nível, mais voltada para o Android para fazer o que você deseja.

Comment: Quanto à sua pergunta do motivo: é difícil saber sem ver o código todo. Mas vale uma dica: evite o uso de membros estáticos quando estiver trabalhando com orientação a objetos a não ser que tenha um ótimo motivo, **especialmente** no Android. Isso pode te trazer bugs bastante sutis e difíceis de desvendar.

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma olhada no uso de AsyncTasks pra ver se soluciona o meu problema e também seguir essas suas dicas. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Bons estudos. :)